# Impossible to manage Actice Directory users on Google Cloud

Tags: active-directory, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to setup Active Directory on Google Cloud Platform. I have successfully created a managed AD domain, defined the password for the `setupadmin` account, created a Windows VM on this domain, and I'm able to login on this VM as setupadmin (I followed this https://cloud.google.com/managed-microsoft-ad/docs/connect-to-active-directory-domain)

As the setupadmin user, I'm able to launch "Active Directory Users and Computers", accordingly to this doc https://cloud.google.com/managed-microsoft-ad/docs/manage-active-directory-objects?hl=fr, but the "new" user option is deactived, and not available in the right click options. It seems I can only list the OU's and objects.

[image]

It is the correct way of managing AD users on GCP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right place to create users, groups and computers is under the Cloud folder. Full info [here](https://cloud.google.com/managed-microsoft-ad/docs/faq#how_can_i_manage_organizational_units_ou)